# Make RewriteRule work in root only

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How do I redirect to `foo.php` without having to type the full address, if both `/foo.htm` and `/foo.php` are in the same domain and folder?

I'm sure that there's a better way to do such redirect than:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo\.htm$ "http://www.bar.com/foo.php" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, but could you elaborate your question?

Comment: I tried to substitute `"http://www.bar.com/foo.php"` with `/foo.php` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^foo\.htm$ /foo.php [R=301,L]
```

Please remember that leading `/` is not matched in .htaccess so your regex would be `^foo\.htm$` instead of `^/foo.htm$

Comment: The leading slash on the first directive was the culprit. As usual, thanks again.